# why each time i need to add the same element in file when everytime i compile the program again

Tags: c

I'm able to add new element in the periodic table and it is added in the file..but problem is that when i search for the newly inserted element after compiling it next time, but it say's particular element is not found in a file. why the elememt is not added in the file for permanent?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct element
{
     char nm[15];
     char sym[3];
     char blk[15];
     int atmno;
     float mass;
     char cat[18];
}el;

FILE *fp;
int i,tot=45;
el e[80];
void home();
void search();
void add();

int main()
{

    int i;
    fp=fopen("per.txt","w");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nerror opening file");
        return 0;
    }
    //1st element
    strcpy(e[0].nm,"Hydrogen");
    strcpy(e[0].blk,"Not Specified");
    strcpy(e[0].sym,"H");
    e[0].atmno=1;
    e[0].mass=2;
    strcpy(e[0].cat,"Non Metal");
    //2nd element
        strcpy(e[1].nm,"Lithium");
    strcpy(e[1].blk,"s");
    strcpy(e[1].sym,"Li");
    e[1].atmno=3;
    e[1].mass=6.94;
    strcpy(e[1].cat,"Metal");
    //3rd element
        strcpy(e[2].nm,"Berillium");
    strcpy(e[2].blk,"s");
    strcpy(e[2].sym,"Be");
    e[2].atmno=4;
    e[2].mass=9.02;
    strcpy(e[2].cat,"Metal");
    //4th element
    strcpy(e[3].nm,"Sodium");
    strcpy(e[3].blk,"s");
    strcpy(e[3].sym,"Na");
    e[3].atmno=11;
    e[3].mass=22.99;
    strcpy(e[3].cat,"Metal");
    //5th elemnt
    strcpy(e[4].nm,"Magnesium");
    strcpy(e[4].blk,"s");
    strcpy(e[4].sym,"Mg");
    e[4].atmno=12;
    e[4].mass=24.31;
    strcpy(e[4].cat,"Metal");
    //6th element
        strcpy(e[5].nm,"Potassium");
    strcpy(e[5].blk,"s");
    strcpy(e[5].sym,"K");
    e[5].atmno=19;
    e[5].mass=39.10;
    strcpy(e[5].cat,"Non Metal");
    //7th element
    strcpy(e[6].nm,"Calcium");
    strcpy(e[6].blk,"s");
    strcpy(e[6].sym,"Ca");
    e[6].atmno=20;
    e[6].mass=40.08;
    strcpy(e[6].cat,"Metal");
    //8th elment
        strcpy(e[7].nm,"Rubidium");
    strcpy(e[7].blk,"s");
    strcpy(e[7].sym,"Rb");
    e[7].atmno=37;
    e[7].mass=85.47;
    strcpy(e[7].cat,"Metal");
    //9th element
    strcpy(e[8].nm,"Strontium");
    strcpy(e[8].blk,"s");
    strcpy(e[8].sym,"Sr");
    e[8].atmno=38;
    e[8].mass=87.62;
    strcpy(e[8].cat,"Metal");
    //10th element
    strcpy(e[9].nm,"Scandium");
    strcpy(e[9].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[9].sym,"Sc");
    e[9].atmno=21;
    e[9].mass=44.96;
    strcpy(e[9].cat,"Metal");
    //11th element
    strcpy(e[10].nm,"Titanium");
    strcpy(e[10].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[10].sym,"Ti");
    e[10].atmno=22;
    e[10].mass=47.88;
    strcpy(e[10].cat,"Metal");
    //12th element
    strcpy(e[11].nm,"Vanadium");
    strcpy(e[11].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[11].sym,"V");
    e[11].atmno=23;
    e[11].mass=50.94;
    strcpy(e[11].cat,"Metal");
    //13th element
    strcpy(e[12].nm,"Chromium");
    strcpy(e[12].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[12].sym,"Cr");
    e[12].atmno=24;
    e[12].mass=52;
    strcpy(e[12].cat,"Metal");
    //14th element
    strcpy(e[13].nm,"Mangnese");
    strcpy(e[13].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[13].sym,"Mn");
    e[13].atmno=25;
    e[13].mass=54.64;
    strcpy(e[13].cat,"Metal");
    //15th element
    strcpy(e[14].nm,"Iron");
    strcpy(e[14].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[14].sym,"Fe");
    e[14].atmno=26;
    e[14].mass=56.08;
    strcpy(e[14].cat,"Metal");
    //16th element
    strcpy(e[15].nm,"Cobalt");
    strcpy(e[15].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[15].sym,"Co");
    e[15].atmno=27;
    e[15].mass=58.93;
    strcpy(e[15].cat,"Metal");
    //17th element
    strcpy(e[16].nm,"Nickel");
    strcpy(e[16].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[16].sym,"Ni");
    e[16].atmno=28;
    e[16].mass=58.69;
    strcpy(e[16].cat,"Metal");
    //18th element
    strcpy(e[17].nm,"Copper");
    strcpy(e[17].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[17].sym,"Cu");
    e[17].atmno=29;
    e[17].mass=63.55;
    strcpy(e[17].cat,"Metal");
    //19th element
    strcpy(e[18].nm,"Zinc");
    strcpy(e[18].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[18].sym,"Zn");
    e[18].atmno=30;
    e[18].mass=65.39;
    strcpy(e[18].cat,"Metal");
    //20th element
    strcpy(e[19].nm,"Palladium");
    strcpy(e[19].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[19].sym,"Pd");
    e[19].atmno=46;
    e[19].mass=106.44;
    strcpy(e[19].cat,"Metal");
    //21th element
    strcpy(e[20].nm,"Silver");
    strcpy(e[20].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[20].sym,"Ag");
    e[20].atmno=47;
    e[20].mass=107.9;
    strcpy(e[20].cat,"Metal");
    //22nd element
    strcpy(e[21].nm,"Cadmium");
    strcpy(e[21].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[21].sym,"Cd");
    e[21].atmno=48;
    e[21].mass=112.4;
    strcpy(e[21].cat,"Metal");
    //23rd element
    strcpy(e[22].nm,"Lanthanium");
    strcpy(e[22].blk,"d");
    strcpy(e[22].sym,"La");
    e[22].atmno=57;
    e[22].mass=138.9;
    strcpy(e[22].cat,"Metal");
    //24th element
    strcpy(e[23].nm,"Boron");
    strcpy(e[23].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[23].sym,"B");
    e[23].atmno=5;
    e[23].mass=10.81;
    strcpy(e[23].cat,"Metalliod");
    //25th element
    strcpy(e[24].nm,"Carbon");
    strcpy(e[24].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[24].sym,"C");
    e[24].atmno=6;
    e[24].mass=12.01;
    strcpy(e[24].cat,"Non Metal");
    //26th element
    strcpy(e[25].nm,"Nitrogen");
    strcpy(e[25].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[25].sym,"N");
    e[25].atmno=7;
    e[25].mass=14.01;
    strcpy(e[25].cat,"Non Metal");
    //27th element
    strcpy(e[26].nm,"Oxygen");
    strcpy(e[26].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[26].sym,"O");
    e[26].atmno=8;
    e[26].mass=16;
    strcpy(e[26].cat,"Non Metal");
    //28th element
    strcpy(e[27].nm,"Flourine");
    strcpy(e[27].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[27].sym,"F");
    e[27].atmno=9;
    e[27].mass=19;
    strcpy(e[27].cat,"Non Metal");
    //29th element
    strcpy(e[28].nm,"Neon");
    strcpy(e[28].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[28].sym,"Ne");
    e[28].atmno=10;
    e[28].mass=20.18;
    strcpy(e[28].cat,"Non Metal");
    //30th element
    strcpy(e[29].nm,"Aluminium");
    strcpy(e[29].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[29].sym,"Al");
    e[29].atmno=13;
    e[29].mass=26.98;
    strcpy(e[29].cat,"Metal");
    //31st element
    strcpy(e[30].nm,"Silicon");
    strcpy(e[30].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[30].sym,"Si");
    e[30].atmno=14;
    e[30].mass=28.09;
    strcpy(e[30].cat,"Metalloid");
    //32nd element
    strcpy(e[31].nm,"Phosphorous");
    strcpy(e[31].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[31].sym,"P");
    e[31].atmno=15;
    e[31].mass=30.97;
    strcpy(e[31].cat,"Non Metal");
    //33rd element
    strcpy(e[32].nm,"Sulphur");
    strcpy(e[32].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[32].sym,"S");
    e[32].atmno=16;
    e[32].mass=32.06;
    strcpy(e[32].cat,"Non Metal");
    //34th element
    strcpy(e[33].nm,"Chlorine");
    strcpy(e[33].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[33].sym,"Cl");
    e[33].atmno=17;
    e[33].mass=35.45;
    strcpy(e[33].cat,"non Metal");
    //35th element
    strcpy(e[34].nm,"Argon");
    strcpy(e[34].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[34].sym,"Ar");
    e[34].atmno=18;
    e[34].mass=39.95;
    strcpy(e[34].cat,"Non Metal");
    //36th element
    strcpy(e[35].nm,"Gallium");
    strcpy(e[35].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[35].sym,"Ga");
    e[35].atmno=31;
    e[35].mass=69.72;
    strcpy(e[35].cat,"Metal");
    //37th element
    strcpy(e[36].nm,"Germanium");
    strcpy(e[36].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[36].sym,"Ge");
    e[36].atmno=32;
    e[36].mass=72.64;
    strcpy(e[36].cat,"Metalloid");
    //38th element
    strcpy(e[37].nm,"Arsenic");
    strcpy(e[37].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[37].sym,"As");
    e[37].atmno=33;
    e[37].mass=74.92;
    strcpy(e[37].cat,"Metalloid");
    //39th element
    strcpy(e[38].nm,"Selenium");
    strcpy(e[38].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[38].sym,"Se");
    e[38].atmno=34;
    e[38].mass=78.96;
    strcpy(e[38].cat,"Non Metal");
    //40th element
    strcpy(e[39].nm,"Bromin");
    strcpy(e[39].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[39].sym,"Br");
    e[39].atmno=35;
    e[39].mass=79.90;
    strcpy(e[39].cat,"Non Metal");
    //41st element
    strcpy(e[40].nm,"Krypton");
    strcpy(e[40].blk,"p");
    strcpy(e[40].sym,"Kr");
    e[40].atmno=36;
    e[40].mass=83.79;
    strcpy(e[40].cat,"Non Metal");
    //42nd element
    strcpy(e[41].nm,"Cerium");
    strcpy(e[41].blk,"f");
    strcpy(e[41].sym,"Ce");
    e[41].atmno=88;
    e[41].mass=140.10;
    strcpy(e[41].cat,"Metal");
    //43rd element
    strcpy(e[42].nm,"Thorium");
    strcpy(e[42].blk,"f");
    strcpy(e[42].sym,"Th");
    e[42].atmno=90;
    e[42].mass=232;
    strcpy(e[42].cat,"Metal");
    //44th element
    strcpy(e[43].nm,"Uranium");
    strcpy(e[43].blk,"f");
    strcpy(e[43].sym,"U");
    e[43].atmno=92;
    e[43].mass=238;
    strcpy(e[43].cat,"Metal");
    //45th element
    strcpy(e[44].nm,"Plutonium");
    strcpy(e[44].blk,"f");
    strcpy(e[44].sym,"Pu");
    e[44].atmno=94;
    e[44].mass=244;
    strcpy(e[44].cat,"Metal");


    for(i=0;i<45;i++)
    {

        fprintf(fp,"%s %s %s %d %f %s",e[i].nm,e[i].sym,e[i].blk,e[i].atmno,e[i].mass,e[i].cat);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    home();
    return 0;
}
void home()
{
      int opt;
      printf("\n\t\t***********************PERIODIC TABLE***********************");
      printf("\n\n\n1.SEARCH ELEMENT\n\n2.ADD ELEMENT\n\n3.EXIT\n\nEnter Your Choice:");
      scanf("%d",&opt);
      if(opt<1||opt>3)
      {
        printf("\nInvalid Choice\nEnter Valid Choice:");
        scanf("%d",&opt);
      }
      switch(opt)
      {
        case 1:
            search();
            break;
        case 2:
            add();
            break;

        case 3:
            return ;
      }
}

//here it searches for a particular element in a file
void search()
{
    int i,j,cho,on,flg=0;
    char mn[50];
    float wt;
    printf("\n1.By Name\n\n2.By Atomic No\n\n3.By Atomic Mass\n\n4.Back to Homescreen\n\nEnter Your Choice:");
    scanf("%d",&cho);
    if(cho<1||cho>4)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid Choice\nEnter Correct Choice between 1&4:");
        scanf("%d",&cho);
    }
    switch(cho)
    {
        case 1:
             printf("\nEnter Name Of Element:\n\t\t");
             scanf("%s",mn);

             for(j=0;mn[j]!='\0';j++)
             {
                if(j==0&&(mn[j]<=122&&mn[j]>=97))
                     mn[j]-=32;
                else
                {
                   if(j!=0&&(mn[j]>=65&&mn[j]<=90))
                     mn[j]+=32;
                   else
                      break;                            
                }

             }
              for(i=0;i<tot;i++)
              {
                if(strcmp(mn,e[i].nm)==0)
                {
                    flg=1;
                    printf("\nName:%s \nSymbol:%s \nBlock:%s \nAtomic No:%d \nAtomic Mass:%f \nCategory:%s",e[i].nm,e[i].sym,e[i].blk,e[i].atmno,e[i].mass,e[i].cat);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(flg==0&&i==tot-1)
                    printf("\nNot found");
                }
              } 
            home();
            break;
        case 2:
                printf("\nEnter Atomic No:");
                 scanf("%d",&on);
                for(i=0;i<tot;i++) 
                {
                    if(on==e[i].atmno)
                    {
                        flg=1;
                        printf("\nName:%s \nSymbol:%s \nBlock:%s \nAtomic No:%d \nAtomic Mass:%f \nCategory:%s",e[i].nm,e[i].sym,e[i].blk,e[i].atmno,e[i].mass,e[i].cat);
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        if(flg==0&&i==tot-1)
                            printf("\nNot found");
                   }
            }
            home();
            break;
        case 3:
                printf("\nEnter Exact Atomic Mass upto 2 decimal places:");
                scanf("%f",&wt);
                 for(i=0;i<tot;i++) 
                 {
                    if(wt==e[i].mass)
                    {
                      flg=1;
                     printf("\nName:%s \nSymbol:%s \nBlock:%s \nAtomic No:%d \nAtomic Mass:%f \nCategory:%s",e[i].nm,e[i].sym,e[i].blk,e[i].atmno,e[i].mass,e[i].cat);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(flg==0&&i==tot-1)
                            printf("\nNot found");
                    }

                }
                home();
                break;
        case 4:
                home();

   } 
}

//Here, is the add function which adds the element in a file
void add()
{
        int n,j;
        FILE *fp1;
        fp1=fopen("per.txt","a");
        if(fp1==NULL)
        {
            printf("\nFailed to open");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nEnter Number of Elements You Want to Add:");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            for(i=tot;i<tot+n;i++)
            {
            printf("\nName of element:\n\t\t");
            scanf("%s",e[i].nm);
            for(j=0;e[i].nm[j]!='\0';j++)
             {
                if(j==0&&(e[i].nm[j]<=122&&e[i].nm[j]>=97))
                     e[i].nm[j]-=32;
                else
                {
                   if(j!=0&&(e[i].nm[j]>=65&&e[i].nm[j]<=90))
                     e[i].nm[j]+=32;
                   else
                      break;                            
                }
              }
            printf("\nSymbol:\n");
            scanf("%s",e[i].sym);
            printf("\nBlock:\n");
            scanf("%s",e[i].blk);
            printf("\nAtomic No:\n");
            scanf("%d",&e[i].atmno);
            printf("\nAtomic Weight:\n");
            scanf("%f",&e[i].mass);
            printf("\nType of Element:\n");
            scanf("%s",e[i].cat);   
            fprintf(fp1,"%s %s %s %d %f %s",e[i].nm,e[i].sym,e[i].blk,e[i].atmno,e[i].mass,e[i].cat);
        }
    }
    tot+=n;
    fclose(fp1);
    home();
    return ;        
}
```

Comment: Post post a [mcve].  Nobody is going to read all that code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Also, I haven't seen a case of "goto syndrome" this bad since 1996... Seriously, learn how subroutines work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never reading the file. When the program starts, you initialize the array and write to file. When element is added, you add to the array and add to the file. But the old data is never retrieved.

You should try to open the file first, if the file is not there, then write the initialization data. If the file is there, then don't write the initialization data, instead go straight to read the file, and initialize the element array.

Change the write format so that the data is separate by comma, this will make it easier to read the data later. Each line should end with `"\n"`

```
char filename[] = "per.txt";
int main()
{
    int i;
    FILE *fin = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(fin == NULL)
    {
        FILE *fout = fopen(filename, "w");
        if(fout)
        {
            if(fout == NULL)
            {
                printf("cannot read/write...\n");
                return 0;
            }

            el x[] =
            {
                { "Hydrogen",  "H",  "ns",  1,  2,      "Non Metal" },
                { "Lithium",   "Li", "s",   3,  6.94f,  "Metal" },
                { "Berillium", "Li", "s",   4,  9.02f,  "Metal" },
                { "Sodium",    "Na", "s",   11, 22.99f, "Metal" },
            };

            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                fprintf(fout, "%s, %s, %s, %d, %f, %s\n", 
                    x[i].nm, x[i].sym, x[i].blk, x[i].atmno, x[i].mass, x[i].cat);
        }
        fclose(fout);
        fin = fopen(filename, "r");
    }

    if(fin == NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot read...\n");
        return 0;
    }

    tot = 0;
    while(fscanf(fin, "%[^,], %[^,], %[^,],%d,%f, %[^\n]\n",
        e[tot].nm, e[tot].sym, e[tot].blk, &e[tot].atmno, &e[tot].mass, e[tot].cat) == 6)
    {
        tot++;
    }

    home();
    return 0;
}

void add()
{
    ...
    fprintf(fp1, "%s, %s, %s, %d, %f, %s\n", 
            e[i].nm, e[i].sym, e[i].blk, e[i].atmno, e[i].mass, e[i].cat);
    ...
    tot += n;
    fclose(fp1);
    home();
    return;
}
```